# BackgroundAudioPlayer and StorageFile WP

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, storage, плеер

Написал плеер под WP 8.1 на С#, осталось реализовать фоновый агент, но...

Как воспроизвести трек типа `StorageFile` с помощью `BackgroundAudioPlayer` (хотя, может, есть и другой вариант фонового воспроизведения)?

Как я понял, для воспроизведения через `BackgroundAudioPlayer` требуется передать объект типа `AudioTrack`, который при объявлении состоит из Uri, title, artist... Но Uri, получаемый свойством Path `StorageFile`, имеет вид `"C:\Data\Users\PUBLIC\Music\2.mp3"` и не хочет приниматься, пробовал гуглить или же смотреть пример фонового агента (например, на сайте мс) -  везде читается файл либо с изолированного хранилища, либо с инета по ссылке, а с телефона нигде.

Есть как вариант копировать файл в изолированное хранилище и затем удалять, но это ж похоже на полный бред и ускорение износа памяти.

Заранее спасибо. )

Answer (score 1):

Никак:

> The BackgroundAudioPlayer can only
> play files from isolated storage or
> from a remote URI.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202978(v=vs.105).aspx

Копируйте в IS.